# How to read address book from a broken phone?

Tags: contacts

A friend of mine dropped his Nokia and it has a crack across the upper half of the screen.

Now the touch screen is unresponding on the whole device but the lower right corner.

I wanted to extract the address book from it and connected it via USB to a Windows 7 PC but I can only see the storage folders of the phone nothing internal.

Is there a tool or something that lets you extract the address book and maybe also all SMS?

Comment: All your contacts get synchronized with your outlook account. You can retrieve by logging in to your outlook account

Answer (score 1):

The address book will be synced with the online address book(s) used when setting up the phone, so it should just be a case of choosing the same online accounts when setting up the repaired phone.